# InvalidComponentError for logstash-output-opensearch

Tags: logstash, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, logstash-file, opensearch-dashboards

I am using Opensearch:2.11 and Logstash:7.16.1
Getting below error while creating index pipeline.

```
Failed to install template {:message=>"bad component(expected absolute path component): _template/logstash",:exception=>URI::InvalidComponentError,:backtrace=>["uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:771:in check_path'",   "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:819:in path='",
```

My conf file looks like

```
output {
  opensearch { 
    hosts => ["${ES_HOSTS}"]
     auth_type => { 
              type=> 'aws_iam'   
              region => 'us-east-1'    
              service_name => 'es'     
          }  
    index => "indexname"
    document_id => "%{docId}"
  }
}
```

Tried creating index pipelines with logstash-output-opensearch plugin using aws iam auth. My aws creds are stored in .creds file, so not providing them in config.

Detailed Logs:

```
[2024-01-10T14:33:28,154][INFO ][logstash.outputs.opensearch][gartner-en-event-agenda] Installing OpenSearch template {:name=>"logstash"}
```

[2024-01-10T14:33:28,171][ERROR][logstash.outputs.opensearch][gartner-en-event-agenda] Failed to install template {:message=>"bad component(expected absolute path component): _template/logstash", :exception=>URI::InvalidComponentError, :backtrace=>["uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:771:in `check_path'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:819:in` path='", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:193:in `initialize'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/generic.rb:138:in` build'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/uri/http.rb:62:in `build'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:176:in` sign_aws_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:154:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/pool.rb:270:in` perform_request_to_url'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/pool.rb:257:in `block in perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/pool.rb:346:in` with_connection'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/pool.rb:256:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client/pool.rb:264:in` block in Pool'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client.rb:388:in `template_put'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client.rb:82:in` template_install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:37:in `install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:25:in` install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:412:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:247:in` finish_register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:224:in `block in register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/opensearch/common.rb:83:in` block in after_successful_connection'"]}